# mysql | Request from empty column and FIND_IN_SET

Tags: php, mysql, request, find-in-set

I have a table:

```
id  name   position   status
1   A      1,2        1
2   B      1          1
3   C                 1
4   D      2          1
```

Where: `position` column is a text field;
My request is here:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE `status`=1
AND `position` >  ''
AND `position` = FIND_IN_SET( 1,  `position` ) 
OR  `position` = FIND_IN_SET( 2,  `position` )
```

This request will return: 1,2,3,4. This is a wrong as I need: 1,2,4 ->
Condition: (`position` >  '').
Where is a problem and how to change my request?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to check if position is empty while you checking numbers in field list .

you dont need to check `position = FIND_IN_SET....` . it will return the value where 1 is in position.

you need to do it like that:

```
 SELECT `id` 
 FROM  `table` 
 WHERE `status`=1
 AND  FIND_IN_SET( 1,  `position` ) 
 OR   FIND_IN_SET( 2,  `position` )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84eaf/1)