# SQL query doesn't work's

Tags: php, mysql

I have used this query but it doesn't work's with my data, i have attached the snapshot of data in my database as well.

[image]

MYSQL Query is as follow's:

```
SELECT * FROM hotPropertyAlert WHERE FIND_IN_SET('E2', locations) AND ( 'parking' = 'H' )
```

Once the query is executed didn't return's the result.

[image]

Thank's in advance...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: never bothered checking for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parking, being a column name, should not be quoted:

```
SELECT * FROM hotPropertyAlert WHERE FIND_IN_SET('E2', locations) AND ( parking = 'H' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Find_in_set return the index of the searche string so you should check if find_in_set is  > 0

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM hotPropertyAlert 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('E2', locations) > 0 AND ( parking = 'H' )
```

Comment: Comparing to 0 isn't necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480418/mysql-request-from-empty-column-and-find-in-set

Comment: I don't compare if is equal to  zero .. but if is greater . .. this mean that the string is in set